# Bundle multiple git repositories in one project

Tags: git, github

Currently, I am working on a larger software project which incorporates multiple github repositories.

To simplify my setup consider the following:

- repo A contains a server app
- repo B holds a desktop client app
- repo C maintains a database API integrated as git submodules into A and B

I have recently started to use the project management features of github.com more to track issues, pull requests & tasks. I was wondering if there is a way to bundle A, B & C under one project. It was difficult to find documentation about all of this, because project and repository are used interchangeably a lot of times.

Note, I am not looking for a way to merge repos A, B & C. I just need a way to manage and review A, B & C tasks, issues, etc. against each other.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: AFAIK if you want to leverage Git's comparison tools, then your projects would have to be in the same repo or maybe at least related via a fork.

Comment: This borders on being off-topic. We're not to recommend tools or external resources.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Sorry, I wasn't sure about being so specific on the matter either, but finding so many other git related posts on stack overflow I thought it's all right to ask. On a not so serious note, you're username isn't too secretive about 'recommended tools' either.

Comment: Yeah. I can understand (why I commented, but didn't flag, etc). As for the username, I've had it since 2003 and I can't be bothered to adopt a new one.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. No worries at all, I wasn't trying to blame you. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are multiple ways to do what your trying to do.
Some organizations do one large repo with all their subprojects in it. [Facebook](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-Facebook-have-so-much-of-their-source-code-in-1-giant-git-repo-did-they-not-think-that-this-approach-wont-scale) and [Google](https://cacm.acm.org/magazines/2016/7/204032-why-google-stores-billions-of-lines-of-code-in-a-single-repository/fulltext) are both known to do this with their applications and services.
You could do:

```
organization repo:
    - serverappfolder
    - desktopclientapp
    - databaseapi
```

Then use the github project management to manage issues for everything together. 
Projects sometimes have something called epics (there are other alternative terminology instead of this). Another option would be to continue to use 3 separate git repos, but create a new master one for managing large issues linked to issues in more than one. As a result, you could continue to use 3 separate repos and create a new one that just has big issues (the epic) that would link or have references to the issues in these other subprojects.

E.g. organizationglobalissues with issues such as (usermanagement, security, etc)

then your 3 repos with a link back to these issues. databaseapi - issue register user - linked to usermanagement global epic.

If your using the database api integrated into the ui's you could keep them separate or just in a .gitignored folder for each of the ui clients that you copy the build to.

Comment: ok thanks for the advice. I was thinking about the "global" repo, too. If I went that route, I would probably integrate the server, client and api bits as submodules, so they would keep in synch with master of their respective repo.